# canvg not working for svg with image element?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvg

I am working on converting `svg to png`. For this conversion I am using `canvg`. This conversion is working fine for normal `svg` with svg elements like `rect` and `circle`, But it doesn't work for svg which contain `image` element.I searched a lot but i didn't found any solution.

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bbND7/10/), which i have tried with image element.

I don't know what is happening wrong here. How to use canvg for svg image elements.
Any suggestions should be appreciated.

**NOTE :** Here is the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bbND7/9/) with svg circle

Comment: You'd have to encode the image data as a data URI. Privacy restrictions in browsers mean that what you give to drawImage must be complete in a single file.

Comment: Hi karthik, did you manage to get this to work? I hav tried @RobertLongson suggestion without success. canvg returns a blank image every time I include an image in the SVG xml. Thanks!